# Swift 2.2 - Value of type ViewController has no member action

Tags: ios, swift

I have been getting the error "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'action'"

(action being the function)

Here is the code I am using for the function and Gesture Recogniser

```
   let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.action))

    uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2

    Map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)

    func action(gestureRecogniser: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        print("Gesture Recognised")


    }
```

`let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.action))`

This is where the error occurs at self.action

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: `func action(gestureRecogniser: UIGestureRecognizer, action) {` is not a valid function header in Swift . And it is unclear where you declared the function. Show whole method which contains the line `let uilpgr = ...`.

Comment: @OOPer, I updated the code and it is `func action(gestureRecogniser: UIGestureRecogniser) {` but it still shows up with the same error. Please help!

Comment: @Sausage Modulation Matrix, I did not create the ViewController as it was made when I made the project. The ViewController comes as made by default. So I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Now it also shows the error"No method declared with Objective-C selector 'action'" on the same line of code: `let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.action))` all aimed at the `#selector(self.action)`. Why is this there as well?

Comment: Do you have the action function defined inside some other function?

Comment: @EpicGamer_1 , you have fixed the first point I pointed. But the second point is still unclear. Please read Blake Lockley's answer and check your code. If you do not understand what he means, you need to show whole methods which are containing the code shown now.

Comment: @OOPer, I realized after I fixed my code the warning went away within 10 minutes, so Blake Lockley's answer was the full answer to the problem. It is gone now. Thank You!

Comment: @EpicGamer_1 , Thanks for reporting. Knowing that your issue is fixed is my pleasure. Good luck for you and for your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `action` is declared locally within the same method that is creating the gesture recognizer.

To resolve this move your `action` method outside of the method it is currently in. So that is is its own method of the class `ViewController` and not inside any other functions.

Comment: That filed ther error,"Value of Type 'ViewControlller' has no member 'action'", but it still shows the warning "No method declared with Objective-C selector 'action'" on the same line of code. What do I do here?

Comment: I will mark this as the correct answer because it runs the program, but I still want to know about the warning. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

the accepted Blake Lockley's answer was right before Swift 4; however in Swift 4, the code need to be changed to the following in order to be compiled correctly (add the @objc marker to the target function):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()

  let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.action))
}

@objc func action(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer){

  print("receives gesture")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working on Xcode 8:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()

  let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.action))
}

func action(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer){

  print("receives gesture")

}
```